# Generate a number for a combination of columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-data-warehouse

I have a requirement to generate an ID field for a combination of a few fields in SQL Server. Let me give you an example.

I have a table like below

| Brand | Owner | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pip | People | Online |
| whip | People | Online |
| Pip | People | Offline |
| zip | Demons | Online |
| Rip | Zombies | Online |
| Dip | Ghosts | Online |

I need to derive BrandID for the distinct BrandName and Owner Combination (irrespective of their source)

I have written SQL like the following which got me the desired output.

```
Select
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Brand,Owner) AS BrandID,
  Brand AS BrandName,
  Owner AS BrandOwner,
  Source
From derivdTable
```

generate the output as

| BrandID | BrandName | Owner | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dip | Ghosts | Online |
| 2 | Pip | People | Online |
| 2 | Pip | Poeple | Offline |
| 3 | Rip | Zombies | Online |
| 4 | whip | people | Online |
| 5 | zip | Demons | Online |

However, after a few days if I get another entry into my "dervdTable" like

| Brand | Owner | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pip | People | Online |
| whip | People | Online |
| Pip | People | Offline |
| zip | Demons | Online |
| Rip | Zombies | Online |
| Dip | Ghosts | Online |
| Bip | People | Online |

Then my output with the same SQL will change like this.

| BrandID | BrandName | Owner | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bip | People | Online |
| 2 | Dip | Ghosts | Online |
| 3 | Pip | People | Online |
| 3 | Pip | Poeple | Offline |
| 4 | Rip | Zombies | Online |
| 5 | whip | people | Online |
| 6 | zip | Demons | Online |

Basically the query changed the brandIDs.

If I had BrandID=2 for Pip, I want to keep the same number forever. How do I get it.

I want my output to look like this

| BrandID | BrandName | Owner | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dip | Ghosts | Online |
| 2 | Pip | People | Online |
| 2 | Pip | Poeple | Offline |
| 3 | Rip | Zombies | Online |
| 4 | whip | people | Online |
| 5 | zip | Demons | Online |
| 6 | Bip | People | Online |

All the new brands should take newID numbers although the orderby caluse in Dense_Rank assigns a different ID.

I don't mind changing the table structure if auto Increment or any other type of settings make me achieve this.

Comment: Seems like an identity column is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your database structure does not respect the fundamentals of the relational principles.

You need to have BrandName as a separate table with an ID that can be autogenerated.

The way to do that is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS BRAND_ID, BrandName
INTO BrandTable
FROM   MyTable:

ALTER TABLE BrandTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (BRAND_ID);

ALTER TABLE  MyTable ADD BRAND_ID INT;

UPDATE MT
SET    BRAND_ID = MT.BRAND_ID
FROM   MyTable AS MT
       JOIN BrandTable AS T 
          ON MT.BrandName = T.BrandName;

ALTER TABLE  MyTable ADD FOREIGN KEY (BRAND_ID) REFERENCES BrandTable (BRAND_ID);
```

Comment: so which table is the final table? MyTable or BrandTable? I understood the need of two tables but I didn't fully understood the implementation.

Comment: You need to have the two tables do deal with